# Variable that depends on another variable

Tags: adjectives

In a software system, we allow users to define variables. The variables can be related to one another using mathematical formulas (for example, A = B + 1).

If a change of value of a variable A affects variable B, we would call B a "dependent variable".
How should we call the variable A - that is, a variable that is affected by a change of another variable?

Comment: Is your issue about dependent and independent variables?

Comment: You seem to mean "How should we call the variable A - that is, a variable **that affects** a change of another variable?"

Comment: I'm actually looking for an adjective to describe a variable that is affected by change of another variable (A is affected by change of B in my example).

Answer (score 1):

If B is the *dependent* variable, then I would refer to A as the **determinant** variable.